# ASP.NET: Disallow certain Active Directory users

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Windows authentication. I would like for our staff to be able to use the application without having to log in. However, we have certain generic, departmental IDs that are in Active Directory as users. How can I make my application disallow these users, so that if a staffperson is logged in to a computer with one of these generic ideas, the application will make them log in?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the non-user accounts a member of the "Users Group", or is there any group that separates the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the restricted department users into an AD Group, then you could put it in your web.config under authorizations denying that specific group privileges.

See below for example (DepartmentIDs would be your AD group):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />

        <authorization>
            <allow roles="DomainName\AuthorizedUsers" />
            <deny users="DomainNames\DepartmentIDs" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Users you can also specify as

```
  <deny users="comma-separated list of users">
```

Or you can deny roles. There are quite a few options here. You can also do permissions in IIS directly, depending on Web Application, Virtual Directory, NTFS Directory access. I'd stick with web.config, but I'm sure you'll hear from other people a few different options.

I also read an interesting article about identity impersonate in .NET, take a look:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=VS.90%29.aspx